# Why Spark's First Iteration is slow and further iterations are faster?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

If we are running spark job, lets say logistic regression in spark,

for the first iteration spark will take around 80s and further it will take 1s why is that so ?

Whats the internal behavior of spark here ? i know spark stores the data in-memory thats why computation is faster but detailed explanation would be good!

Comment: Where do you run our jobs cluster or standalone? Also please provide code snippet which affected

Comment: maybe the 80s includes initialization,cluster deploy and so on.

Comment: @FaigB take any spark code. i am asking just a theoretical question.

Answer (score 2):

Few things:

1. First iteration can contain sending code to workers, etc.
2. Most of ML algorithms caches input data in memory. Cache is lazy, so in the first iteration whole dataset is cached - moved to RAM - and in next iterations algorithm uses cached data - which is much faster
3. Spark infrastructure must be initialized - parts of the context, executor JVMs

Comment: Don't forget initialization of all the Spark infrastructure (lazy parts of the contexts and such, executor JVMs and such).

Comment: @zero323 Thanks, I've added it :)

Comment: :) I think this is actually the biggest contributor. I remember posting some tests a while ago, and "no-op" jobs exhibit a comparable delay.